# How to read hex from a file and store it in an unsigned char?

Tags: c++, qt

File contains the characters '0', 'x', '5', '1' and a new line.

```
QFile file ("config.txt");

QString fileContent;
if (file.open (QIODevice::ReadOnly))
{
    QString line;
    QTextStream t(&file);
    do
    {
        line = t.readLine();
        fileContent += line;
    } while (!line.isNull());

    file.close();
}

unsigned char m_pduAddress = fileContent.toUInt (0, 16);
```

How to read hex from a file and store it in an unsigned char?

All the decimal to hex conversion functions I have heard of use char*. I have to store the result in unsigned char, not in char*.

Comment: Do you mean the file is 5 characters long ("0x51\n") or two characters long ("Q\n")?  Typical conversion functions take a `const char*` as *input*, and return an int (or unsigned long or whatever).

Comment: What is your question?  Your code seems to do what you need.

Comment: Do your file contains only one row like this: "0x51\n"? it seems correct, but you can do it more simply: fileContent = t.readAll(); pduAddress = fileContent.trimmed().toUInt (0, 16);

Comment: Is it important to use `QFile` rather than the standard streams?

Comment: Does your file contain the *binary* `0x51` or the characters `0 x 5 1`?

Comment: @MartinBonner I have manually types 0x51 there and pressed enter.

Comment: So what is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly read the value from the `QTextStream`:

```
QTextStream t(&file);
int value;
t >> value;
```

This will automatically detect the leading `0x` and read the rest as a hex number.